# R How do I reference a colunm within a list of data.frames? And then use lapply?

Tags: r, list, substr, lapply

Say I had a list of dataframes:

```
DF1 <- data.frame(mtcars)
DF2 <- data.frame(mtcars*2)
mydatalist <-list(DF1,DF2)
```

How would I apply a function on all the columns in a list, and return a list of the results? For example, say I want to extract the first number of the qsec column (the 7th one). I can easily call it up for the first item:

```
mydatalist[[1]][7]
```

But say I wanted to look at all of column 7 for each element in the list (both DF1 and DF2). How would I call that?

This doesn't work:

```
 mydatalist[[]][7]
 Error in mydatalist[[]] : invalid subscript type 'symbol'
```

My purpose is that I want to apply a function to that, say substr:

```
lapply(mydatalist[[1]][7],substr,0,2)
lapply(mydatalist[[2]][7],substr,0,2)
```

But this doesn't work:

```
lapply(mydatalist[[]][7],substr,0,2)
```

How do I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get only the 7th column of each data frame in the list, you can use

```
lapply(mydatalist, "[", 7)  ## you can also get multiple columns with c(1,5,etc)
```

for the column as a data frame, and

```
lapply(mydatalist, "[[", 7)
```

to view it as a vector.  To reference it/them by name, you can use the name just like you would the column number

```
lapply(mydatalist, "[", "qsec")
```

To use `substr` on the column, first you have to access the column. Then you apply can use an anonymous function to do the work with `substr`.

```
lapply(mydatalist, function(x) substr(x[[7]], 0, 2)) ## or x[["qsec"]]
# [[1]]
#  [1] "16" "17" "18" "19" "17" "20" "15" "20" "22" "18"
# [11] "18" "17" "17" "18" "17" "17" "17" "19" "18" "19"
# [21] "20" "16" "17" "15" "17" "18" "16" "16" "14" "15"
# [31] "14" "18"
# 
# [[2]]
#  [1] "32" "34" "37" "38" "34" "40" "31" "40" "45" "36"
# [11] "37" "34" "35" "36" "35" "35" "34" "38" "37" "39"
# [21] "40" "33" "34" "30" "34" "37" "33" "33" "29" "31"
# [31] "29" "37"
```

Comment: @Nate this is a great R trick. all or almost all the "special" operators in R are parsed as functions like any other

Comment: @ssdecontrol - and I guess if you use backticks instead of quotes it's slightly faster